# How to make css flex box row auto resizing horizontally with image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When flex-basis:auto is set on a div, the div expands vertically to fit contents.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/knjesznx/1/)

Html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placebacon.net/400/103">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    -- Removed for readability --
  </div>
</div>
```

scss:

```
.parent {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;

  .image {
    flex-basis:auto;
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;

    img {
      width:100%;
      height:auto;
    }
  }

  .text {
    flex-basis:0px;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;

    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
}
```

However this does not work horizontally :

[Example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/knjesznx/3/)

```
.parent {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  .image {
    flex-basis:auto;
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;

    img {
      height:100%;
      width:auto;
    }
  }

  .text {
    flex-basis:0px;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;

    overflow-y:scroll;
  }
}
```

If you resize the height of the parent, the image will change size to preserve aspect ratio. However the flex box retains the size of the image before the transformation.

Is there a CSS property I need to set to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to set an height in  `.parent`, `.image` and finally to `img` to trigger the calculation for each elements : https://jsfiddle.net/knjesznx/4/

You should not mind the flex value unless you have really litlle content aside and a background to show , then just add flex:1 to the container that is suppose to fill all space left [demo](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/XNEgyw)

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100vh;/* here */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.parent .image {
  height: 100%;/* here */
}
.parent .image img {
  height: 100%;/* here */
  width: auto;
}
.parent .text {
  overflow-y: scroll;
 /* eventually use flex:1; to fill all space left*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placebacon.net/103/400">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, been puling my hair out all day over this. Is there a specification I can read where it describes this quirk?

Comment: @bluelightzero the only specification i can tell about is that height:100%; requires a direct parent to have a usable height set in CSS else it is 100% of nothing. Table and flex element have some funny behavior about this where it sometimes partially works. the case here obviously ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the  and set the image as the background of the image container. The css would look like:

```css
 .image {
    flex-basis:auto;
    flex-grow:0;
    flex-shrink:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    background-image: url('http://placebacon.net/103/400');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: The image is not a fixed width, it is proportional to height.